# Want to return the number of rows in matrix with all zeros in python

Tags: python

I wanted to return a output which is the number of rows with all zero in its elements. Here is my python code, and I couldn't identify where is the bug.

```
def find_bully_1(A):

    n = len(A)
    candidate = 0
    count = 0


    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if A[i][j] == 0:
                count = count + 1
        if count == n:
            candidate = candidate + 1
    return candidate




x = [[1,1,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0]]


find_bully_1(x)

The output should be 2 but it keeps return 1.
```

Comment: You need to reset `count` inside your outer loop before the start of the inner loop. But there are better ways to do this task.

Answer (score 2):

Your code counts *every* zero that it's seen so far, but it should be just counting the zeros in the current row. To fix that you need to reset `count` to zero before you enter the `for j in range(n):` loop.

However, counting all-zero rows this way is inefficient. A much better way is to use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function in conjunction with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or `all`. For example:

```
def find_bully_1(a):
    return sum(not any(u) for u in a)

x = [
    [1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
]

print(find_bully_1(x))
```

**output**

```
2
```

---

FWIW, I wouldn't bother putting that code into a function, since Python function calls are relatively slow, and the code required to call the function isn't much shorter than just writing the code itself:

```
print(sum(not any(u) for u in x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`:

```
x = [[1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0]]
new_x = sum(all(not b for b in i) for i in x)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example the count just gets incremented for every 0 forever and never gets reset

You just need to reset your count at the start of the for loop

```
def find_bully_1(A):

n = len(A)
candidate = 0


for i in range(n):
    count = 0 
    for j in range(n):
        if A[i][j] == 0:
            count = count + 1
    if count == n:
        candidate = candidate + 1
return candidate




x = [[1,1,1,1],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0]]


print(find_bully_1(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a vectorised `numpy` solution. See [@PM 2Ring's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) for why your logic does not work.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,1,1,1],
             [0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,0],
             [0,1,0,1],
             [0,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,0]])

np.sum(~x.any(axis=1))  # 3
```

Comment: This is certainly very fast compared to the other approaches; OTOH, not everyone has (or wants to use) Numpy.

Comment: @PM2Ring. this is true. however, I would suggest that numeric arrays should be handled with `numpy` where viable, especially if the workflow involves further numeric array manipulation.

Comment: Sure, especially if the array size is large, or you're doing a _lot_ of calculations. For small arrays, with only a few calculations, the Numpy overheads may end up making the code slower. You need to profile to be sure.